# T-SQL : how to select row with multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have below data set in SQL Server and I need to select the data with conditions in order below:

First, check to see if date_end is 1/1/2099, then select the row that has smallest days gap and `skill_group` is not SWAT for rows have same `employee_id`, in this case that is row 2.

Second, for rows that do not have 1/1/2099 date_end, select row that has most recent day date_end, in this case it's row 4.

```
ID  employee_id last_name   first_name  date_start  date_end    skill_group
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   N05E0F  Mike    Pamela  12/19/2013  1/1/2099    SWAT
2   N05E0F  Mike    Pamela  9/16/2015   1/1/2099    Welcome Team
3   NSH8A   David   Smith   12/19/2013  9/16/2016   Unlicensed
4   NSH8A   David   Smith   8/16/2015   10/16/2016  CMT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Here are some of them:

**[`top with ties`](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option)** version:

```
select top 1 with ties
    *
  from tbl
  where skill_group != 'SWAT'
  order by 
    row_number() over (
      partition by employee_id
      order by date_end desc, datediff(day,date_start,date_end) asc 
      )
```

---

[**`with common_table_expression as ()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) using **[`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)** version:

```
with cte as (
  select  *
      , rn = row_number() over (
              partition by employee_id
              order by date_end desc, datediff(day,date_start,date_end) asc 
            )

    from tbl
    where skill_group != 'SWAT'
)
select *
  from cte
  where rn = 1
```

---

Comment: Thank you for your help.